Cómo medir el tráfico de una web cuando hay un iframe dentro y lo considera todo tráfico directo
Tengo una página web que, dentro de ella tiene un iframe. La gestión de cookies para la web principal está configurada con Cookieyes.
En ambas, tengo insertado el mismo track de Google Tag Manager (el iframe es un software donde he metido el GTM-)
Mi web considera que gran parte del tráfico es DIRECTO, porque al cargar el iframe lo recoge así. Además, creo que pueden estar duplicándose las visitas entre web e iframe.
He revisado que el orden de los scripts sea el correcto y contrastado con cookieyes esto.
¿Qué puedo hacer?
gracias, un saludo

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
